# Accessing a structure without a structure name

Tags: c

In this code below I want a pointer to union and use that pointer to access the member (say) eid(8 bits field) which is defined inside strucutre txcmsgeid.
How can i do that?

```
typedef union uCANTxMessageBuffer 
{
    struct
    {
        txcmsgsid CMSGSID;
        txcmsgeid CMSGEID;

    };
    int messageWord[4];

}CANTxMessageBuffer;
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use the member name.

example

```
void foo()
{
    CANTxMessageBuffer c;
    CANTxMessageBuffer *pc = &c;

    txcmsgsid *ptx;

    c.CMSGSID = value;
    pc -> CMSGSID = value;

    ptx = &c.CMSGSID;
    ptx = &pc -> CMSGSID;
}
```

Full example: https://godbolt.org/z/6tmO2Q